# Display facesontext message in pop up for validating input in a dialog box

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have doubt regarding how to show facescontext messages in a dialog box.
This uses primefaces 4.0, JSF.

I want to display a facescontext message in pop up dialog box (which appears on clicking a commandbutton in another dialog box).

**Method 1 :**
Suppose the view file is like

```
<p:commandButton id=”btn”  oncomplete=”dlg.show()”/>
<p:dialod id=”dlg_id” widgetVar=”dlg”>
    <h:inputText id=”name”/>
    <p:commandButton id=”btn1” actionListener=”someBean.someMethod()” oncomplete=”dlg1.show()”/>
</p:dialog>
<p:dialog id=”dlg1_id” widgetVar=”dlg1”>
    <h:messages id=”error_msgs” value=”#{facesContext.messageList}”
</p:dialog>
```

**BackingBean (someBean)**

```
public void someMethod() {
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().addCallBackParam(“facesMessageAvailable”,true);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(“error_msgs”,new FacesMessage(…,”Name is Required”,…));
    }
```

The above method shows the pop up box. But the value shown in the pop up box is like javax.beans.context@1ggh34ea
Then I tried using UI component binding.

**Method 2 :**

View File

```
<p:commandButton id=”btn”  oncomplete=”dlg.show()”/>
<p:dialog id=”dlg_id” widgetVar=”dlg”>
    <h:inputText id=”name”/>
    <p:commandButton id=”btn1” actionListener=”someBean.someMethod()” oncomplete=”dlg1.show()”/>
</p:dialog>
<p:dialog id=”dlg1_id” widgetVar=”dlg1”>
    <h:outputText id=”msg” binding=”someBean.outText”/>
</p:dialog>
```

**BackingBean (someBean)**

```
private UIComponent outText;
//getter and setter of outText
public void someMethod() {
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().addCallBackParam(“facesMessageAvailable”,true);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(outText.getClientId() , new FacesMessage(…,”Name is Required”,…));
}
```

But this shows a blank empty pop up.
Then I tried using JOptionPane. But it produces some logical errors.

I would appreciate any help.
The syntax may be incorrect as i typed the code from my memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your **Method 1** and found there are some mistakes:

### Using `<h:messages>`

1.You should specify `update` attribute of the `<p:commandButton>`.
2.No need to specify `value=”#{facesContext.messageList}”` of `<h:messages>` (And there's also no such attribute).

So, after doing those, your code should like this:

```
    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton id="btn"  oncomplete="dlg.show()"/>

        <p:dialog id="dlg_id" widgetVar="dlg">
            <h:inputText id="name"/>
            <p:commandButton id="btn1" actionListener="#{someBean.someMethod()}" oncomplete="dlg1.show()" update="dlg1_id"/>
        </p:dialog>

        <p:dialog id="dlg1_id" widgetVar="dlg1">
            <h:messages id="error_msgs"/>
        </p:dialog>

    </h:form>
```

And the result looks like:
[image]

---

### Using `<h:message>`

It's using `<h:messages>` above, while you may want to use `<h:message>` as you seems want the message show for `error_msgs`. To do so, you need to specify the **client_id** instead of **id**, so try this:

**Page:**

```
    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton id="btn"  oncomplete="dlg.show()"/>

        <p:dialog id="dlg_id" widgetVar="dlg">
            <h:inputText id="name"/>
            <p:commandButton id="btn1" actionListener="#{someBean.someMethod()}" oncomplete="dlg1.show()" update="dlg1_id"/>
        </p:dialog>

        <p:dialog id="dlg1_id" widgetVar="dlg1">
            <h:message for="j_idt5"/>
        </p:dialog>
    </h:form>
```

**Backing Bean:**

```
public void someMethod(){
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().addCallbackParam("facesMessageAvailable",true);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("j_idt5",new FacesMessage("Name is Required"));
}
```

Note that **`j_idt5`** is the client_id of the `<h:inputText>`.
How can I know the client_id? Just right click on the page in the browser and View page source code, look at the component you are interested in and you'll find the **cliend_id**.