# Popping up a simple text message alert from a function in a java file

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsf

Right now I have a Java file with the function:

```
public void asd() throws SQLException {

    try {
        getConnections();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PSTimer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    MongoCursor<Document> cursor = (MongoCursor<Document>) database.getCollection("Partidoscontagem").find().sort(new Document("data", -1)).limit(1).iterator();
    if (cursor != null && cursor.hasNext()){
            ...
            ...
            ...
    } else {
        /*This is where I want to include the message "No document found"*/
    }
```

And I have a p:commandButton in my html file with the code:

```
<p:commandButton  actionListener="#{bean.asd()}">
```

I'd like to know the correct way of doing a pop up in my html file after I click the p:commandButton, with the text resulting from the function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display facesontext message in pop up for validating input in a dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20865380/display-facesontext-message-in-pop-up-for-validating-input-in-a-dialog-box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.

```xml
<h:form>
    <p:growl id="growl" life="2000" />
    <p:commandButton  actionListener="#{bean.asd()}" update="growl">
</h:form>
```

```java
public void asd() throws SQLException {
    if(foo) {
        // do stuff
    } else {
        addInfoMessage("Eh. That's interesting.");
    }
}


private void addInfoMessage(String summary) {
    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, summary,  null);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
}
```

Comment: And instead of creating all the 'addInfoMessage' methods, better use OmniFaces. http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Messages. And better search for duplicates...

Comment: Probably a good idea, though I'm seldom in favor of adding libraries to my code just to solve one problem